# TypeScript: Use namespaced type argument in generic

Tags: typescript, tslint

I have a generic method

```
abstract run<T> (options: T): void;
```

And then in the implementation, say I want the type of T to be class B which is in namespace A. TSLint complains if I use

```
run <A.B> (options: A.B) : void
```

The error is

```
Type '<A, B>(options: B) => void' is not assignable to type '<T>(options: T) => void'
```

It seems that the dot '.' is being read as ',' ? How should I pass the type?

Comment: What you are showing is not proper TypeScript. Can you provide a complete example?

Comment: When you run it you don't need to use the generics since you said arguments[0] is T, so it can become confused when you give it a generic type T and a different type in the argument, in this case your using the same so it should be fine but it looks strange. 
By the way, Type namespacing (as defined in .d.ts files) should be no problem for typescript. Do you really mean the old TypeScript namespaces? Its a kind of deprecated feature. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a method is generic in a base class it can't be implemented for just one type in the derived class. This would break OOP principles, as you couldn't use the derived class where the base class is expected:

```
namespace A {
    export class B { private x!: string}
}
abstract class Abs {
    abstract run<T>(p: T): void;
}
class Impl extends Abs{
    run(p: A.B) { } // We get an error here as we should but if this were allowed we would get the error below
}

let a: Abs = new Impl();
a.run(""); // Impl expects A.B, but Abs will let us pass in any T not ok
```

**Note** The syntax you use is also wrong, you can only specify concerte types in calls as generic type arguments, you can't use a type in as a type parameter in a function/method declaration. There is no syntax for this because it generally makes no sense as outlined above.

A good option would be to move the generic type parameter to the class instead:

```
namespace A {
    export class B { private x!: string}
}
abstract class Abs<T> {
    abstract run(p: T): void;
}
class Impl extends Abs<A.B>{
    run(p: A.B) { } // ok now
}

let a: Abs<A.B> = new Impl();
a.run(new A.B()); // type safe
```